# Video Subtitles Specification [CHK and PAC]

Tags: video, subtitles

I'm wondering if any of you have experience dealing with CHK and PAC subtitles.

I'm working on a project (from a software point of view) and we need to open these subtitles and convert them into a *nicer* format that can be used by some standard media players.

So my 2 questions are:

- Does anyone know the specification of the subtitle format? (this is bit technical, but will help us open the file and transform the contents to whatever we want)
- Does anyone know any application that can transcode these subtitles to other formats?

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpfull [Subtitle-Edit](http://codecpack.co/download/Subtitle-Edit.html) for .PAC subtitles.
The .PAC subtitle format is binary format
For other subtitle format, .CHK is far I know the file format for "Chunks" or fragments of hard disk after doing CHCKDISK command. But also the CHK file extension is associated with the SSConvert application used to distribute data format containing multiple streams (typ. languages) of subtitle text, timing and presentation style data for video.